# Zookeeper 3.5.x backwards compability with zookeeper 3.4.x clients

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

Looking at upgrading several zookeeper clusters from 3.4.(6-10) to a more recent version (3.5.7 or 3.6.0) and we are having hundreds of microservices (java) that are running the the zookeeper 3.4.x clients.

Will the server upgrade break existing clients.

Plan is to start upgrading clients to 3.5 once server is upgraded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is quite out-dated [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/ReleaseManagement) from the zookeeper team as well as information in the [release notes](https://zookeeper.apache.org/releases.html). My own testing gives me the following results:

- 3.4.x clients **compatible** with 3.5.x server
- 3.4.x and 3.5.x clients can be mixed on 3.5 server
- 3.5.x clients **incompatible** with 3.4 server